# Multiprocessing concatenate the resultant pandas dataframe of each process

Tags: python-2.7, multiprocessing

I am using multiprocessing to run multiple process to achieve parallelism in my program. I cannot figure out how to get the resultant pandas dataframe from each process and once all process are done concatenate the dataframes. Please see the  code below:
Python version : 2.7

```
import pandas as pd
import multiprocessing
import numpy as np

def process_df(filtered_df,dp, ch):    
    df = np.asarray(filtered_df.vol)
    filtered_df['fcst'] = df[len(df)-1]
    ## more columns and processing.
    return filtered_df

def target_function(data_df,dp, ch):

    filtered_df = data_df[(data_df['dp'] == dp ) & (data_df['ch'] == ch )]
    result = process_df(filtered_df,dp, ch)
    print(result)
    return result


data_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'wk': {0: '201301', 1: '201302', 2: '201303', 3: '201304', 4: '201305'},
    'dp': {0: '0003', 1: '0003', 2: '0003', 3: '0003', 4: '0003'},
    'ch': {0: '0110', 1: '0110', 2: '0110', 3: '0110', 4: '0110'}, 
    'vol': {0: 1073, 1: 9113, 2: 1021, 3: 3223, 4: 2929}})


if __name__ == "__main__":

    jobs = []
    list_iter = np.unique(data_df['dp'] + '|' + data_df['ch']).tolist()

    for dp_ch in list_iter:
        dp,ch = dp_ch.split("|",1)
        process = multiprocessing.Process(target=target_function,args=(data_df,dp,ch))
        jobs.append(process)   

    # Start the processes 
    for j in jobs:
        j.start()

    # Ensure all of the processes have finished
    for j in jobs:
        j.join()

    print(process)
```

Comment: Your approach does not allow to pass results back from the workers, unless you setup some queues. It is easier to use a process `Pool` and call the `map` method to get your results back. See also here: https://pymotw.com/3/multiprocessing/communication.html#process-pools

Comment: thank you!. Map does not really allow multiple arguments, I need to pass dataframes to the target function. I can pass those as global variables (basically define outside main function.) but that loads them each time a process is spawned .

Comment: You can use `.starmap()` instead of `.map()` to pass multiple arguments. For that, you first pack your arguments as a `tuple()` and add them to an _iterable_ (e.g. a `list()`).